# Adding double variable validation to my program

Tags: c

i want to do adding double value validation to my program.

For ex: When user input string, it gives error "Please enter an integer instead of string."

i also want that "Please enter an integer instead of double value."

How can i apply this?

```
/*
 * HW3-3.c
 *
 *  Created on: Oct 21, 2012
 *      Author: mert
 */


 #include <string.h>
 #include <stdio.h>

  void checkTriangle(char *s1,char *s2,char *s3)
  {
    int i;
    int found_letter = 0;
    int len = strlen(s1);
    int len2 = strlen(s2);
    int len3 = strlen(s3);

    for( i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if(s1[i] < '0' || s1[i] > '9')
        {
            found_letter = 1; // this variable works as a boolean
            break;
        }
    }


    for( i = 0; i < len2; i++)
    {
        if(s2[i] < '0' || s2[i] > '9')
        {
            found_letter = 1; // this variable works as a boolean
            break;
        }
    }


    for( i = 0; i < len3; i++)
    {
        if(s3[i] < '0' || s3[i] > '9')
        {
            found_letter = 1; // this variable works as a boolean
            break;
        }
    }

    if(found_letter) // value 0 means false, any other value means true
        printf("Please enter an integer instead of string.");
    else
    {
            int side1 = atoi(s1);
            int side2 = atoi(s2);
            int side3 = atoi(s3);

            if ((side1 + side2 > side3 && side1 +  side3 > side2 && side2 + side3 > side1) && (side1 > 0 && side2 > 0 && side3 > 0))
                 {
                // Deciding type of triangle according to given input.
                  if (side1 == side2 && side2 == side3)
                      printf("EQUILATERAL TRIANGLE");
                  else if (side1 == side2 || side2 == side3 || side1 == side3)
                      printf("ISOSCELES TRIANGLE\n");
                  else
                      printf("SCALENE TRIANGLE \n");
                }
                 else
                     printf("\nTriangle could not be formed.");
    }
  }


  int main(void)
  {

      char s[32], s2[32], s3[32];

      printf("Please enter sides of triangle");
      printf("\nPlease enter side 1:");
      gets(s);
      printf("Please enter side 2:");
      gets(s2);
      printf("Please enter side 3:");
      gets(s3);

      checkTriangle(s,s2,s3);
  }
```

Comment: Use strtol(), complain if it doesn't stop on the end of the string.  And use error messages designed for users, not programmers, like "Please enter a valid number".

Comment: @HansPassant: speaking as both a user and a programmer, I *do not* like to be told that my input was not a "valid number" in either role. It is no use to know that `-4.6E-7` isn't "valid", I need to know what *is* considered valid. I do agree though that audiences other than programmers can't be expected to know specifically what "double" means. You might get away with "integer" for a mathematically literate audience, although there's a risk of frustrating someone who expects `1E6` to be accepted as an integer. "Valid number" is ambiguous unless you accept every numeric format imaginable.

Comment: Yes, it is common for users to complain about an error message but then not provide a better one.

Comment: @Hans: well, if you're only willing to accept a bug report that solves the problem reported, then I'd propose, "Please enter a valid integer consisting only of a series of digits 0-9". It would be nice also to add, "rejected character: %c" but that's a bigger code modification. That should deal with people who unwittingly enter "1,000" or "1.000" (one of which is an attempt to specify 1000, and the other an attempt to specify 1, depending on locale). But I would point out that you complained about an error message and provided a *worse* one, so I'll take no snarking from you ;-)

Comment: There's another option, which is less work for the programmer that identifying exactly what was wrong and more robust in a way, but more work for the user. Just say "invalid input" but also print the program's usage message, including a definition of any/all accepted input formats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try parsing the input and check the results. Note also that it is convenient to use a general function and not repeat three times the validation:

```
/*
    Returns a positive integer if a positive integer was read from input.
    It will return -1 if the input is not a number,
    -2 if it was not an integer,
    -3 if it was not strictly positive.

    Bugs: "-0" is recognized as "not a number" instead of "not positive"
          "0185" is recognized as 185 instead of "not a (proper) number"
*/

int askValue(char *message)
{
    int val;
    char s[32];
    printf("%s: ", message);

    // Read string
    fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin);

    // Trim string. fgets will return the \n.
    if (0 == strlen(s))
        return -1;
    s[strlen(s)-1] = 0x0;

    // Parse as an integer. 0 means it was either "0", or garbage
    if (0 == atoi(s))
    {
        if ('0' == s[0])
            val = 0; // It was a "0" (or maybe "0.17" or "0x18")
        else
            return -1; // Error: it was not a number
    }
    // Then parse as a float. "0.17" will give 0.17 which is not 0.00
    if ((double)val != atof(s))
    {
        // Error: the string checks as a floating point value
        return -2;
    }
    if (val <= 0)
        return -3;
    return val;
}

void complain(int val)
{
    switch(val)
    {
        case -3: printf("Value must be greater than 0\n"); break;
        case -2: printf("Value must be integer\n"); break;
        case -1: printf("Value must be a number\n"); break;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int side1, side2, side3; // We could use a vector: side[3]

    while ((side1 = askValue("Please enter side 1")) < 0)
        complain(side1);
    while ((side2 = askValue("Please enter side 2")) < 0)
        complain(side2);
    while ((side3 = askValue("Please enter side 3")) < 0)
        complain(side3);

    ...
}
```

This is a different implementation, more strict. It returns the integer value if it is positive, -2 if it was a negative integers, and -1 in all other cases (garbage and floats).

It still has a false negative for "-0", which parses as "0".

```
int askValue(char *message)
{
    int val;
    char s[32], c[32];
    printf("%s: ", message);

    // Read string
    fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin);

    // Parse as an integer. 0 means it was either "0", or garbage
    val = atoi(s);

    // Now produce the expected input for val, included final \n
    snprintf(c, sizeof(c), "%d\n", val);

    if (strcmp(c, s))
        return -1;
    if (val < 0)
        return -3;
    return val;
}
```

Comment: This will recognize suspicious inputs like `123abc` as integers too; this seems to be the main reason OP decided to check the input by characters

Comment: when i enter integer value it still says vaValue must be greater than 0

Comment: True. I added a more strict implementation, which generates the expected input for any given positive integer and rejects the input if it does not match.

Comment: Sorry mert, I am a moron. I had forgotten that in the input there will also be a carriage return \n. So you're inputing "17\n" and this is not "17", and the system rejects it. Modified. NOTE: on Windows systems, you need "\r\n" instead of "\n".

Answer (score 0):

While going through each character, you can simply check if any of the digits is a `.`. If you find one that is, then the input is a double.

```
  void checkTriangle(char *s1,char *s2,char *s3)
  {
    int i;
    int found_double = 0;
    int found_letter = 0;
    int len = strlen(s1);
    int len2 = strlen(s2);
    int len3 = strlen(s3);

    for( i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if(s1[i] < '0' || s1[i] > '9')
        {
            found_letter = 1; // this variable works as a boolean
            break;
        } else if (s1[i] == '.') {
            found_double = 1;
            break;
        }
    }


    for( i = 0; i < len2; i++)
    {
        if(s2[i] < '0' || s2[i] > '9')
        {
            found_letter = 1; // this variable works as a boolean
            break;
        } else if (s2[i] == '.') {
            found_double = 1;
            break;
        }
    }


    for( i = 0; i < len3; i++)
    {
        if(s3[i] < '0' || s3[i] > '9')
        {
            found_letter = 1; // this variable works as a boolean
            break;
        } else if (s3[i] == '.') {
            found_double = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(found_letter) // value 0 means false, any other value means true
        printf("Please enter an integer instead of string.");
    else if (found_double)
        printf("Enter an integer, not a double");
    else {
        // code stays the same
    }
```

Comment: @mertmetin: Are you still having that `'.'` problem? From [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12999808/how-can-i-write-test-driver-for-this-program), it seems like you've got past that phase.